# Android Content Box - custom listview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

how can I make  content boxes with different text layers in Android (see picture):
[image]

The boxes will be shown as a list (list view).

Any suggestion, links and tutorials about the subject are welcome!

Thank you very much.

/Jasper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a listview with a custom layout, that layout will hosts one row (gray + green color).
Here is an example : http://hmkcode.com/android-custom-listview-items-row/